# access docker daemon remote api in contanier

Tags: docker, centos7

I use official version of docker-ce at centos7, start a docker daemon in container:

```
[root@5cae7be526b4 /]# rpm -qa docker-ce
docker-ce-17.09.0.ce-1.el7.centos.x86_64
```

Here is my daemon config

```
{
"hosts": ["unix:///var/run/docker.sock", "tcp://0.0.0.0:5555"],
"live-restore": true,
"insecure-registries": ["172.17.0.6:9980"]
}
```

Without changing config, docker daemon can start and restart in container:

```
[root@5cae7be526b4 /]# docker info
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 17.09.0-ce
Storage Driver: vfs
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 06b9cb35161009dcb7123345749fef02f7cea8e0
runc version: 3f2f8b84a77f73d38244dd690525642a72156c64
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core) (containerized)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 16
Total Memory: 31.26GiB
Name: 5cae7be526b4
ID: N3Y4:VTIJ:WCHK:AQL3:MU3F:DNHE:BIXO:7ISI:4D4V:Q4IG:VYIT:FOH3
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: bridge-nf-call-iptables is disabled
WARNING: bridge-nf-call-ip6tables is disabled
```

But change the config, it failed:

```
[root@5cae7be526b4 /]# systemctl restart docker 
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@5cae7be526b4 /]# systemctl status docker -l
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Thu 2017-11-02 05:51:02 UTC; 2s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 260 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 260 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 02 05:51:02 5cae7be526b4 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Nov 02 05:51:02 5cae7be526b4 systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Nov 02 05:51:02 5cae7be526b4 systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Nov 02 05:51:02 5cae7be526b4 systemd[1]: docker.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 02 05:51:02 5cae7be526b4 systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for docker.service
Nov 02 05:51:02 5cae7be526b4 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Nov 02 05:51:02 5cae7be526b4 systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Nov 02 05:51:02 5cae7be526b4 systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
```

Of course, this daemon config can run at host.

I has start container with `--privileged` and `-v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup` to enable use `systemctl` in container.

The root cause is `"hosts": ["unix:///var/run/docker.sock", "tcp://0.0.0.0:5555"]`, i do not know how to fix it but i need to set host indeed.

I want to make this container as a repo and start other container to do docker action like `pull` from this docker daemon.

How can i enable it?

Comment: Administration, not programming. You might get better help on super user

Comment: i had tried but no help.

Comment: Well, it's not going to be better here, where your question is off-topic

Comment: The key of my question is customized config which makes me confused, i do not think it off-topic

Comment: configuration != programming.

Answer (score 0):

I share my solution here, please tell me if wrong or has a better way.

First, check docker version, only new official version can run in container. For centos, it means docker-ce, refer to https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/centos/

Second, check the host port doesn't be set as `-p` when start container. docker daemon can listen it and specify with `-p` would make conflicts.

Third, start docker daemon in container should assign a volume for storage. If not, the storage option only can be `vfs`.